# Why is an array not moved after the for block like a vector?

Tags: rust

I'm new to this language and am currently reading Rust in action. I understand why you're able to access the vector after a `for` loop. However, I don't understand why this works:

```rust
let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for item in list {
    println!("{}", item);
}
println!("{:#?}", list);
```

If I try the same with a vector, it doesn't work without it being a reference inside the `for`, which I understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arrays of numbers are never moved. Arrays are [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) if their underlying type is `Copy`, which means that, like basic numerical types, they're always *copied* rather than moved. They're eligible for this special treatment since an array is just a contiguous chunk of the bytes representing its elements, so if its elements can be copied byte-by-byte, then so can the whole array. A vector, on the other hand, involves dynamic allocation and pointers, so blindly copying the bytes of a vector isn't safe.

When you use a `for` loop, you're invoking [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) on the type, which takes `self` by value. For a type that's *not* `Copy`, this requires the target of the `for` loop to be *moved* to construct the iterator. But for types that are `Copy`, Rust [makes a copy of the array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-%5BT;+N%5D) and then uses that copy in `into_iter` instead.

As the relevant documentation (linked above) says:

> [...] Creates a consuming iterator, that is, one that **moves** each value out
> of the array (from start to end). The array cannot be used after
> calling this **unless T implements `Copy`**, so the whole array is **copied**.

*emphasis mine*